# Passing Value from a window to a listbox on another window -- C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The value gets passed and added but when I go to that window it doesn't get added to the list box. The value gets added to the collection but not the list box. 
I found that if I try to add another value it will overwrite the original (The count is always equal to 1, The image is from the third time passing the string).
When Explaining can you explain it easily cause I am only a beginner. 
All I want to figure out first is getting it printing to the list box.

Window 1

```
    ObservableCollection<string> Modules = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public void PassedThroughWindow(string _module)
    {
        string moduleName = _module;

        //Data not being printed to the listbox
        Modules.Add(moduleName.ToString());
        lbxTimeTable.ItemsSource = StringModules;
    }
```

Window 2

```
        string ModuleName = TbxModuleName.Text;

        //Passing Data To Main Window
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.PassedThroughWindow(ModuleName);
```

Debug From Window One:
[image: Debug From Window One]

Comment: I was parsing the string to another instance of the form. Thanks for the Help Guys  :)

Comment: Both Windows should use a common view model instance (in their DataContext property). Search the web for MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value to a new instance of your mainwindow, not to the existing one

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
main.PassedThroughWindow(ModuleName);
```

That's why it doesnt show up in your existing MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

```
ObservableCollection<string> Modules = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public MainWindow()
{ 
      //Assign item source only once and try adding items it should help
      lbxTimeTable.ItemsSource = Modules;
}  

public void PassedThroughWindow(string _module)
{
    string moduleName = _module;

    //Data not being printed to the listbox
    //Change stringModules to Modules which is defined above
    Modules.Add(moduleName.ToString());

}
```

Also one more point, where is StringModules is defined?. Define only one mainwindow instance and pass data.

Comment: String Module is what it was originally called. I changed to Modules